# Show flexible, data-aware Gantt Chart Segments in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gantt-chart

For some reason, the X axis is plotted with fixed spacing which does not represent the actual time periods.
The black tenure segements all have the same size although they should show the different tenure periods.

I tried the two optiones below but the axis does not change.:

```
scale_x_date(limits = c(as.Date("06.10.2017","31.12.2020")))

min <- ("06.10.2017")
max <- ("31.12.2020")
scale_x_date(limits = c(min, max))
```

The three black segments should be as long according to the length of the respective tenure (i.e. end date - start date)
I do not understand how to solve this.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(name = c(
  "Hank Kowalski",
  "Bruce Kippler",
  "Gerd Jennson"),

  start = c(   
    "31.12.2020",
    "01.07.2018",
    "06.10.2017"),
  
  end = c(
    "03.11.2019",
    "03.11.2019",
    "30.06.2018")
   )

data %>%
  mutate(start=as.Date(start,'%d.%m.%Y'),
         end=as.Date(end,'%d.%m.%Y'), #'%d.%m.%Y'
         name=factor(name,levels = unique(name),ordered = T)) %>%
  mutate(start=as.character(start),
         end=as.character(end)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=start, xend=end, y=name, yend=name)) +
  geom_segment(size=3) +
  labs(title='Team Coaches', size= 6, x='Tenure', y='Coach') +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(CDU = 'black', FDP = 'yellow', Grüne = 'green' , parteilos = 'grey', SPD = 'red')) +
  theme_wsj() + 
  theme(axis.title = element_text(),text = element_text(size=8),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(lineheight = 2, size = 6))
```

Comment: Remove the `mutate(start=as.character(start), end=as.character(end))`, by coercing to character they are no longer dates, `ggplot` will in its turn coerce the dates to factor and you'll have increments of 1 in the x axis. *If this works*, delete the question or VTC as simple error?

Comment: but with this, the X-Axis is no longer chronologically sorted.

Comment: Yes, it is. It is sorted by date.

Answer (score 0):

Here is evidence that if the coercion to character is removed the x-axis is still ordered by date.
I have commented out `theme_wsj` because I am having trouble with its fonts.

```
data %>%
  mutate(start=as.Date(start,'%d.%m.%Y'),
         end=as.Date(end,'%d.%m.%Y'), #'%d.%m.%Y'
         name=factor(name,levels = unique(name),ordered = T)) %>%
  #mutate(start=as.character(start),
  #       end=as.character(end)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=start, xend=end, y=name, yend=name)) +
  geom_segment(size=3) +
  labs(title='Team Coaches', size= 6, x='Tenure', y='Coach') +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(CDU = 'black', FDP = 'yellow', Grüne = 'green' , parteilos = 'grey', SPD = 'red')) +
  #theme_wsj() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(),text = element_text(size=8),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(lineheight = 2, size = 6))
```

[image]